# Want to fetch unread emails from gmail

Tags: php, gmail

I want to know that how can i fetch unread emails from gmail account. I have a gmail account i want that all the unread emails from gmail accounts are coming to my site though php. I have been implementing various codes but they are not helping me. Please help me to solve this problem.

I have a code which i am using for fetching mails from gmail, But the mails are not being fetch.

```
<?php 
/* connect to gmail */

$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'abc@gmail.com';
echo $password = 'abcd';

/* try to connect */
$inbox =  imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
 echo "got inbox";
/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox);

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {
  echo "got emails";
  /* begin output var */
  $output = '';

  /* put the newest emails on top */
  rsort($emails);

  /* for every email... */
  foreach($emails as $email_number) {
    /* get information specific to this email */
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

    /* output the email header information */


    $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
    $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
    $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
    $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
    $output.= '</div>';

    /* output the email body */
    $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
     break;
  }

  echo $output;
} 

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
?>
```

Comment: Do any errors occur? If so, what ones?

Comment: Give some more information about the errors you are receiving to help people giving you a better answer

Comment: I didn't receive any error so that's why i am confuse, where i am wrong

Comment: Basically you tried http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap this tutorial and you could not get the expected result so you are asking us to give you a code which will full fill your requirements. Is that it?

Comment: Dibya if you have code which full fill my requirements than i 'll be very thankful to you

Answer (score 2):

for fetching unread messages do:

```
$inbox =  imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
$unread_msgs = imap_search($inbox, 'UNSEEN');
```

you can refer the corresponding [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php) as well for other options.

Answer (score 1):

Use `imap_open`:

```
$inbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX",$username,$password);
```

See an example [here](http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap).

Comment: I am not asking you I am blaming the OP for asking this type of question. Never mind question is flagged.

Comment: No problem. I just feel, that i also should have noticed it. ;)